# can't get scope_identity after insert in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, ado

I have to do a quick and dirty sql session storage for classic asp so I have the following stored procedure that does the inserting work.  When I run it from sql management studio or through asp code, it inserts fine but it's not returning the scope_identity.  What's odd is that when I execute the procedure from code I'm getting "operation is not allowed when the object is closed" error message on the line where it checks for rs.eof.

```
create procedure InsertSessionValue

    @keyname varchar(50),
    @value varchar(max)

as

    declare @ID int
    delete from storedsessionsimple where datesaved < dateadd(d, -1, getdate())

    insert into dbo.StoredSessionSimple (SessionKey, SessionValue, DateSaved) values (@keyname, @value, getdate())

    set @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    return @ID
```

and the asp code is...

```
set cnLocal = GetConnection()
    cnLocal.open()

    set rs = cnLocal.execute("exec InsertSessionValue '" & SessionKey & "','" & SessionValue & "'")
    if not rs.eof then
        id = rs(0)
    end if
    rs.close: set rs = nothing
    end if
    cnLocal.close: set cnLocal = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `RETURN` in your stored proc is typically used for returning a status or error code. If you want to return data as a recordset from your stored proc, use `SELECT` instead of `RETURN`.

**Update:** It sounds like it's still not picking up that your stored procedure is now returning a recordset. According to the MSDN documentation for an ADO Command:

> If the command is not intended to return results (for example, an SQL UPDATE query) the provider returns Nothing as long as the option adExecuteNoRecords is specified; otherwise Execute returns a closed Recordset.

Comment: right.  good call.  but unfortunately I still get the object closed error on the "if not rs.eof then" line.

Comment: Even when you use `SELECT` instead of `RETURN` in your stored proc?

Comment: yes, I've made that change and it still gives the same error.

Comment: interesting.  so any ideas how I can make it "pick up" the update?

Comment: Do you get a value now when you execute your stored procedure from server management studio?

Comment: Yes.  This is getting more strange.  I did a response.write(cnLocal.State) directly after my execute code and it came back as 1-open.  But on the very next line where it checks eof is where I get the error.  Is it possible that the recordset is closed but the connection isn't?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I've moved the code from the stored procedure directly to the execute statement so I'm not even calling the SP now.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure will need a couple changes if you want to return the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` in a recordset. The way it is currently implemented the IDENTITY is being returned as a RETURN_VALUE parameter, which you would have to retrieve using the ADO Command object. The return value will be the first parameter in the [Command.Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675869%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) collection. See the following [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103538/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/tips/t100901-1.shtml) for an example.

If you want to return the results in a recordset then try changing the line

```
set @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

to

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS NEW_ID
```

and removing the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use

```
set nocount on ;
```

Your Sql Insert Query with ";"

```
set nocount off ;
```

And use bellow method

```
Set rsInsert = conn.execute(SQLQuery)


if not rsInsert.EOF then
   response.write(rsInsert(0))
end if
```

It works fine. I tested.